# "Texture of X" vs "texture of the X."

Tags: word-usage, grammar

Which is the correct option in cases like these:

> My hands felt the silky texture of fabric.
>
> My hands felt the silky texture of the fabric.

Or they mean different things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean different things.

*Silky texture of the fabric* refers to a particular piece of fabric.

*Silky texture of fabric* refers to the texture of fabric in general.  It doesn't really make sense since there are many kinds of fabric with different textures, they aren't all silky.  You could instead say the texture of silk.